# A Cruncher Program

Tags: c, algorithm

I was writing a program where I have to remove all the consecutive repeated occurance of a sub-string in increasing order of length starting at 1.

For example if string is "abcabeccced".
After removing repeated sub-string of length 1: "abcababceccced" --> "abcababceced" (2 'c' are removed)
After removing repeated sub-string of length 2: "abcababceced" --> "abcabceced" (substring “ab” is removed)
and so on...

Can someone suggest an efficient code for this or even a idea how to do it?

Comment: Should it be more efficient than two loops / O(N*N) ?

Comment: Actually There is no such restriction.But I am Looking For a Simpler Logic with high efficiency.I found one solution at http://ds-gyan.blogspot.com/2010/01/string-cruncher.html but looking for a better approach.

Comment: @MrLister, No I just found it while solving some programming problems. Anyway would It make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested pseudo code, but you're looking to do something like this:

```
 void crunch(char *str)
 {
   for (n=1; n<10; n++)
   {
     ptr = str;
     while (*ptr != '\0')
     {
       while (strncmp(ptr, ptr + n, n) == 0)
         strcpy(ptr, ptr + n);
       ptr++;
     }
   }
 }
```

It could be optimized better, but, I choose to optimize the pseudo code to get the idea across. The problems with this code are:

- It's inefficient because it uses strcpy (a src, dst pointer pair would be better)
- The ptr loop goes to the end of the string, we could abort earlier
- There's a hard coded limit of 10 in there, this could be generalized
- This function overwrites the memory pointed to by str, whereas a copy may be better
- (EDIT) Change inner if to an inner while to 'crunch' repeated sequences.

Comment: That are about the two loops I had in mind. Note: You can replace the outer while() loop by a for() loop, which is probably more readable. I do think you need memmove(), because the strings are overlapping (though the pointers are not). The src/dst pair would avoid this.

Comment: @wildplasser yeah memmove() is a more optimal over strcpy() but it requires you to know the length of the bytes to copy. I know you there are ways to do this in an efficient manner. But, in this case I choose strcpy() because it means I can rely on the NUL terminator and it keeps the pseudo code succinct.

Answer (score 1):

You can program this straight from the definition:

```
input s : string
for len between 0 and s.Length / 2
    for pos between 0 and s.Length - len
        sub = s.substring(from pos to pos + len)
        subSub = sub + sub
        while (s.Contains(subSub))
            s = s.ReplaceAll(subSub, sub)
```

The algorithm tries doubling all substrings of length len, and replace doubled strings with singles.

Comment: Your algorithm may not replace tripled strings to singles like the sample of the triple 'c' being crunched into a single 'c'.

Comment: @BicycleDude You are right, I added a `while` loop to address this.